# Number of recommendation letters while applying through Mathjobs

Tags: mathematics, application, recommendation-letter, job-search, job

I am applying for postdoc positions in math. In MathJobs, I can add 5 recommendation letters (4 for research and 1 for teaching) for any position even if the position specifically asks for 4 letters. Is it advisable to send all the recommendation letters in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions for each job.

Consider five letters instead of four only if you know that all five are very strong and cover different areas of your strengths. And then explain briefly in your cover letter why you are asking the hiring committee to read more than they asked for.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion, which implicitly assumes that an applicant knows the content of the recommendation letters. Personally, I never share this information with applicants for whom I write letters.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, the exception  works only if the OP knows (essentially) what's in the letters. Practice varies: I always show applicants what I plan to write.